# Can't get Android SDK Manager to open

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

Having searched here and elsewhere for answers to my problems, I'm still unable to fix this.

I've installed Eclipse, ADT Plugin, and the Android SDK. My problem is that the SDK Manager won't open, whether it is launched from Eclipse or directly. The command prompt window flashes up briefly, then closes.

I've tried several proposed solutions: Various configurations of my Path and `JAVA_HOME` variables, installation of  the 32 and 64 bit versions of the JDK, running as Administrator, all with no success.

The different components are installed at these paths:

```
JDK - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
JRE - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
SDK - C:\ADT\sdk
```

My JAVA_HOME is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11`
My Path includes `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin` at the beginning.

I've tried reinstalling the SDK and the installer correctly identifies the location of Java, and yet still it won't work.

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm practically tearing my hair out!

Comment: Oh, I'm using 64-bit Windows 8, forgot to mention this.

Comment: See this -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open

Comment: I just wanted to give the appropriate attention to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open again. It's the correct solution. The below do not address the problem as such.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Open cmd,

go to android sdk folder,

in tools/lib/, edit find_java.bat,

you will see the lines like below, add black line to your file and save.

> rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path. The return code will
>
> rem be 0 if the command worked or 1 if the exec failed (program not
>
> found). for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -t') do set java_exe=%%a

this

> **set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java.exe"**
>
> if not defined java_exe goto :CheckFailed
>
> :SearchJavaW
>
> rem Check if we can find a javaw.exe at the same location
>
> than java.exe. rem If that doesn't work, just fall back on the
>
> java.exe we just found. for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -t -w')
>
> do set javaw_exe=%%a if not exist %javaw_exe% set javaw_exe=%java_exe%
>
> **set javaw_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java.exe"**

i hope it helps

Comment: Excellent! This solved the problem. I think it was the set javaw_exe part that was missing from all the other answers. Thank you!

Comment: If this does not work try setting environment variable 'ANDROID_SWT' to point to the folder where swt.jar is located (should match your architecture, 32 or 64 bit). For example: d:\android-sdk\tools\lib\x86_64

Comment: thanx its very helpful ...but what is JAVA_HOME ..and how to set [ath for it

Comment: I use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14392081/248616 By just running the `android.bat` file and works

Comment: I'm getting an "unrecognised command" error. I have done exactly as shown in the lines. I'm guessing there is some syntax error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: pls double check your java path

Comment: Note: If you can't find the find_java.bat file, go into cmd and type "dir /s/b \find_java.bat" and it will tell you the location of each find_java.bat file.

Answer (score 19):

Answer by Talha is correct. Just adding that you might need to NOT include quotation marks in the black lines in his solution.

The following addition worked for me:

```
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java.exe
```

Comment: just added this one and it worked! thanks to you and @Talha.
As a note, just watch out when you update JAVA because probably it will break every time, since its pointing to a version specifically.

Comment: This solution is bad because it will break everytime you update Java. At least use JAVA_HOME instead.

Answer (score 2):

Found out what the cause of this problem was in my case: In the registry, there was a setting to have the CMD using UTF-8 (chcp=65001).

If I double click `C:\Programmer\Android\SDK Manager.exe`, I get the described symptoms.

If double click `C:\Programmer\Android\sdk\tools\lib\SDK Manager.exe` there is a hint:
`A pop-up stating: Failed to execute tools\android.bat`

Starting a CMD window in `C:\Programmer\Android\sdk\tools` and running `android.bat`, gave no output, even if editing the file and reming out the initial `@echo off`. Running the command `chcp` returned 65001.

So changing the codepage with chcp 850 and then running android.bat again, I got output, ending with the line: `call lib\find_java.bat`. This turned out to be the same problem. Each time a new CMD was spawned, the codepage changed to 65001

Fixed the problem by editing the following registry entry, deleting the value, and everything worked:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->Command Processor->AutoRun: @chcp 65001>nul
```

Having an empty value here, make the CMD using codepage 850, and the bat files begin to work again.

I am not quite sure what has made this change in the first place, but now I know the cure.

Answer (score 1):

When extracting the `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip`, three files were broken:

`("sdk/tools/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar","sdk/tools/lib/find_java.exe","sdk/tools/lib/sdk-common.jar")`

I don't know why but you can replace these files using old versions of android SDK e.g. `android-sdktools_installer_r20.0.1-windows.exe`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching.......and installing...re-intalling.....and changing the path of the android.bat as the answers above mentioned.....the final solution was: running Eclipse or the bat file or Android studio as administrator in windows 8 for the manager to open up!

Answer (score 0):

check the md5 checksum for eclipse and android SDK.It might be an md5 check sum problem.

for calculating the md5 checksum of  files u downloaded you can go to http://www.guidingtech.com/9800/what-is-md5-checksum-how-to-verify-it/

for correct md5 checksum :- 
1. for eclipse go to link their official download site click on 
downloaded package that u downloaded then go to check sum just match it with ur eclipse downloaded file.
2.for android sdk go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and click on download for other platformsand match the md5 checksum (f09aa4557bd1dc2703fde95dcdd6b92e).

i my case i downloaded all that stuff four times.
with regards

ajay

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if you haven't installed Java on your machine. I had a similar problem but after installing java it worked for me. You can download Java from https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml.

Regards,
Abhi

Comment: Eclipse is running so Java is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and it help for me after a long time with all ways above not effect on windows7 64-bits, no need to have `JAVA_HOME` system variable or edit android.bat

1. Download Android Studio within Android SDK, Java JDK 64 bits and Java JRE x86
2. Install Java JRE first, then install Java JDK 64 bits, and the Android Studio last.
3. Now you start Android Studio first (64 bits version) it require to have JAVA_HOME setting to run JVM, just copy the `jdk.x.x.x(version)` folder (my PC: `jdk1.8.0_25` from `"C:\Program Files\Java\")`folder to Android Studio folder and rename that folder (in Android Studio) to "jre" `(jdk1.8.0_25 -> jre)`.
4. Now it work for me to open Android SDK Manager from anywhere, if you want to use eclipse (not official now) just copy the java `jre.x.x.x(version)` x86 folder (from where you install before) to Eclipse and rename to "jre". After coping, choose the Android SDK path in Eclipse to use, It works for both Android Studio and Eclipse.
5. Mind your antivirus if still refusing you (remove antivirus and install after you sure it not cause problem)!

Answer (score 0):

cmd this "android.bat update sdk" ,this way can open "SDK Manager.exe"

note

1."D:\SDK\android-sdk-windows\tools" PATH in enviroment.

2.Replace sdk "tools" folder, this is site -> https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html, then select "Get just the command line tools".(new version deprecated "SDK Manager.exe")
this way worked for my Android Studio 2.3

3.and if "android.bat update sdk" can't work, see this video-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMLVY3PqPlc

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above methods none of them worked.If you have already installed jdk-10 or any other then uninstall it and install jdk-8. If you created the path variables then immediately remove the 'JAVA_HOME' variable and also remove the java path from 'PATH' variable. Then install the jdk-8, and try to install sdk manager it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I found another solution, assuming you have Android Studio installed on your system:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open settings (Control + Alt + S)
3. Locate "Android SDK" setting (Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings)
4. On the right side, you'll have the SDK related tabs

Answer (score -4):

Try This >

Go to sdk folder

Right Click on Sdk Manager then Run as A administrator .
It will open sdk manger and your problem will solve