# eclipse install ADT but nothing change and can`t see any android icon

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

i install ADT in eclipse and when eclipse restart itself i see no changes in eclipse.

i cant see any android icon in eclipse and i dont know what is wrong.

thanks for help.

Comment: Does it show the option for Android projects when you create a new project ?

Comment: yes it show.and i try to create an android project but at the end i cant click finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse go to Window-->Preferences select Android
Check if the sdk location is set correctly.
Eg, the path of sdk should be set to

```
home/..(your path)../adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk
```

the location of the platform-tools directory.

Comment: open Wndow-->Open Perspective-->Other select Java(default). Is this set? otherwise check this link it might help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504325/cant-get-android-sdk-manager-to-open?rq=1)