# Flutter - Build failed during 'assembleDebug'

Tags: android, flutter

In the last one month I don't work with Flutter. Now I can't start apps. I tried everything, but nothing works. If I start to run a basic app, this error message appear in the console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G960F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

Sometimes if I open the android folder and start there the app, it works fine. Maybe the problem is the Android SDK. If I run **flutter doctor** there is an error:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android
    SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or
      visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for
      detailed instructions.
```

I tried to uninstall Flutter and Android Studio - nothing works. It would be great if someone of you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please install necessary build tools as mentioned in error log

Comment: try using flutter clean command then run

Comment: @AR I already tried it. It doesn't change something

Comment: @silentsudo I already installed the sdk tools from https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads. But this doesn't helped me too, because I can't open the sdkManager

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504325/cant-get-android-sdk-manager-to-open