# Android SDK Manager is not opening using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

Android SDK was opening easily few hours ago but after I updated SDK-TOOLS to latest version it started giving me error whenever I try to open SDK-MANAGER using eclipse. The error I am getting is :

```
[2013-06-17 12:03:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'C:\Windows\system32\java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2013-06-17 12:03:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2013-06-17 12:03:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
```

I have checked my `enviorment variable` setting for `PATH` value as well.The path value has **C:\jdk1.6.0_23\bin** path for jdk and System32 jdk comes after that, but still it's using system32 path .I have aslo tried all solutions given on StackOverflow but nothing seems to work for me. I don't know what has gone wrong ?

Please help

Comment: install a new jdk 7 x64 version of the JDK and install "Android SDK Platform-tools" in you sdk manager

Comment: How do I install Android SDK Platform-tools when SDK manager is not opening?

Comment: did you install jdk 7 x64?

Comment: Delete `System32 jdk comes after that`, you don't seem to have your JDK installed under `system32`

Comment: @sunil, why do you think the OP needs to install JDK x64?

Comment: Try to update eclipse and try again. Help-> Check for Updates

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I have tried it also but receives a message - No Updates Found

Comment: Found my [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466572/eclipse-android-sdk-bundle-cant-open-android-sdk-manager?rq=1)

Comment: I have already found my answer....Please check my previous comment