# My SDK Manager in Eclipse will not open

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-manager

I've just started learning to use Eclipse and I a having trouble opening my SDK Manager. Each time I try, the loading bar for starting the SDK Manager gets to around 75% and just closes with no error or warning messages.

When I try to run the SDK Manager from my SDK folder, a console with the following error message came up (shown below). [image]

I then tried sorting out the file path using the following Stack Overflow questions below:

[Can't get Android SDK Manager to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504325/cant-get-android-sdk-manager-to-open)

[Android SDK manager won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open)

I have tried editing both the `find_java.bat` and `android.bat` (according to those mentioned Stack Overflow questions and other sources I found online) but I still can't open my SDK Manager. What else could be the problem and what else can I try to get it working?

Comment: Add the tools folder to Windows environment variables, i.e. PATH variable.

Comment: @ThomasR. How or where would I do that? Sorry I'm still learning how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Press the Windows button and Search for android.bat(in the search programs and files text field)

```
Then copy the file to your android sdk folder 
(C:\Users\Shan\Documents\Computer Science - YEAR 2\Android App Development\adt-
bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\tools\).
```

After that dont run SDK manager but run the android.bat file.

Or try this link:

[Eclipse android sdk bundle can't open Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466572/eclipse-android-sdk-bundle-cant-open-android-sdk-manager)

Comment: I tried that link you suggested there as well and it didn't work either. My android.bat is in my SDK folder already. When you say I must run the android.bat file, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Try starting the SDK from command prompt by using android.bat in the tools folder , Right click on android.bat and choose run as administrator

Comment: Ok I tried it but each time I open the command prompt using the android.bat the prompt opens and immediately closes before I can even get my hands back on the keyboard. How can I make it stay open long enough to try and start the SDK inside it? Also what is the command for starting the SDK inside the prompt?

Comment: see this link :http://techathlon.com/fix-android-sdk-manager-failing-open-android-development-tools-bundle/

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to Windows->Preferences and select Android. Here you should make sure the path to the SDK is correct. 
It should be in a folder called adt-bundle-windows-x86_64

If you can find where SDK Manager.exe is installed that is where the path should be set to in Eclipse with the exception that it points to the sdk folder in that path not the executable.

If the path is correct when you select Apply you should see at least three things in show up in the list of SDK Targets.